# Anonymous Coinbase Transaction

Tags: anonymity

Is there any solution to have anonymous coinbase transaction in ethereum or other Cryptocurrency? Something like using coinjoin for coinbase transactions or something else.

Comment: You have zcash and monero for private transactions.

Comment: I mean anonymity for block reward transaction not for other types of transactions.